# GKE Ingress Using Internal IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a GKE service app using golang. I want to make the app only accessible with same vpc (because it will exposed using kong to public domain). But everytime i make the internal alb ingress inside GKE, it returns an error like this

```
Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer ad8b7iw3-gke-app-event-ingress-n1p8mv91 does not exist: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/gke-project/regions/asia-southeast2/targetHttpProxies/k8s2-tp-ad8b7iw3-gke-app-event-ingress-n1p8mv91'. An active proxy-only subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule.
```

EDITED
For now the error return like this

```
Missing one or more resources. If resource creation takes longer than expected, you might have an invalid configuration.
```

i have make svc and ingress yaml file to handle this:

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: gke-app
  name: event-ingress
  namespace: gke-app
spec:
  ingressClassName: "gce-internal"
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: gke-svc
      port:
        number: 8003
  rules:
    - host: event.staginggke.my.id
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gke-svc
                port:
                  number: 8003
```

svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gke-svc
  namespace: gke-app
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: gke-app
spec:
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    app: gke-app
  ports:
    - port: 8003 # Port output
      targetPort: 8000 # Container port
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
      nodePort: 30473 # Node Port Static
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.184.0.12
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

Thank you for helping!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a proxy-only subnet. You need to create one in the same VPC/Subnet your GKE cluster is on

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#configure-a-network